# Tratamiento de datos Sqlite y Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Buen dia amigos!!!!

Tengo una duda muy básica, es en cuanto al tratamiento de datos los cuales los obtengo de una base de datos, en este caso serian 2 columnas una llamada "estudios_clínicos" y otra "costo" donde un estudio y su costo están en la misma fila prácticamente relacionados, dentro de mi interfaz gráfica los estudios clínicos son seleccionados desde un OptionMenu, y aparecen de una manera muy extraña dejo imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos datos se muestran en una tupla y en la pantalla de la terminal se muestran de otra manera:

```
Dato obtenido del OptionMenu: ('GLUCOSA',)
```

y la tupla esta almacenada con el nombre self.menu_p y se muestra:

```
[('ANTIDOPING EN ORINA',), ('BIOMETRIA HEMATICA COMPLETA BHC',), 
 ('ESPERMATOBIOSCOPIA DIRECTA',), ('EXAMEN GENERAL DE ORINA',), ('GLUCOSA',)]
```

está para que no se llene la pantalla decidi cortar

Quiero obtener el indice de donde se encuentra el estudio GLUCOSA;

```
indice = self.menu_p.index(self.estudio)
```

pero me da como respuesta el error:

```
indice = self.menu_p.index(self.estudio)
ValueError: "('GLUCOSA',)" is not in list
```

Obviamente la respuesta es que no encuentra el valor "('GLUCOSA',)" dentro de la tupla pero está practicamente escrita de la misma manera XD ahora si cambio el tipo de dato como lista con la linea: `self.estudio = list(self.prueba.get())` aparece de esta manera:

```
indice = self.menu_p.index(self.estudio)
ValueError: ['(', "'", 'G', 'L', 'U', 'C', 'O', 'S', 'A', "'", ',', ')'] is not in list
```

Alguien sabe que error estoy cometiendo???

Anexo el código:

```
         #self.menu_desplegable() 
             Label(frame3, text = 'Pruebas Clinicas 1', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10, sticky = W + E)
             self.prueba = tk.StringVar(frame3)
             self.prueba.set('--------------------------------------')
             pruebas = self.menu_p   
             self.menu_prueba = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, self.prueba, *pruebas).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W + E, pady = 10)

      def menu_desplegable(self): # Menu desplegable obtenidos desde la BD
          query = 'SELECT estudios_clinicos FROM price_list ORDER BY estudios_clinicos'
          self.menu_p = self.run_query(query).fetchall()
          if self.menu_p is None :
              self.menu_p = 'No hay estudios'
          else:
              self.menu_p = list(self.menu_p)

     def sumas(self):
           self.estudio = (self.prueba.get()) 
           print(type(self.estudio)) #el tipo de dato obtenido es un String
           print(self.estudio, '\n')
           print(self.menu_p)
           indice = self.menu_p.index(self.estudio)
```

Muchas gracias de nuevo!!!!

Comment: ¿Cómo estás creando el OptionMenu? ¿Usas self.menu_p supongo con una StringVar? Lo digo por la presencia de esos corchetes en algunos nombres... Si lo que quieres es ir sumando el precio de cada uno seleccionado porqué no obtienes las dos columnas (prueba y precio) y usas un diccionario o bien realizas una query por cada estudio que se seleccione y obtienes su precio...

Comment: Buen dia Amigo JFSevilla, como lo acabas de decir con la linea self.prueba = tk.StringVar(frame3) tal como dice arriba, hay alguna forma de quitar esos corchetes???, lo que yo intentaba era sacar el indice del estudio y usar ese mismo indice en una query de precios para que lo busque como vienen en la misma fila me parecio una buena opcion, lo del diccionario no lo pense intentaré hacerlo, me podrias explicar bien lo de la query por cada estudio? es que no me quedo muy claro, gracias amigo!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la query a la base de datos obtienes una lista de tuplas (una por fila) de la forma:

```
[('ANTIDOPING EN ORINA',), ('BIOMETRIA HEMATICA COMPLETA BHC',), 
 ('ESPERMATOBIOSCOPIA DIRECTA',), ('EXAMEN GENERAL DE ORINA',), ('GLUCOSA',)]
```

al agregar cada item al OptionMenu estás agregando la tupla, no la cadena que tiene como primer item, que es lo que te interesa. Al hacer esto, se obtiene una representación en forma de cadena de la tupla `"('GLUCOSA',)"` y se usa como opción del menú.

Cuando obtienes el elemento seleccionado de la `StringVar` consigues la cadena `"('GLUCOSA',)"` no la tupla `('GLUCOSA',)` que es lo que hay en la lista, por lo que `list.index` no la encuentra:

> ```
> >>> l = [('GLUCOSA',), ('ANTIDOPING EN ORINA', )]
> >>> l.index(('GLUCOSA',))
> 0
> >>> l.index("('GLUCOSA',)")
> Exception has occurred: ValueError
>     "('GLUCOSA',)" is not in list
> ```

En vez de agregar a la lista las filas recibidas directamente de la query, deberías agregar solo el nombre de la prueba:

```
self.menu_p = [row[0] for row self.run_query(query)]
if not self.menu_p:
    self.menu_p = 'No hay estudios'
```

No obstante, creo que si pretendes obtener el costo de cada prueba seleccionada, obtener el costo y el nombre de la prueba y usar un diccionario para almacenarlos es más simple.

```
self._pruebas = {prueba: costo for prueba, costo in self.run_query(query)}
self.menu_prueba = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, self.prueba, *self._pruebas.keys())
```

y para obtener el costo solo debemos indizar sobre el diccionario:

```
estudio = self.prueba.get()
costo = self._pruebas[estudio]
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.db_lab = "test.db"
        self._pruebas = {"No hay estudios": None}
        self.obtener_pruebas()

        frame3 = ttk.Frame(self)
        frame3.pack()
        label = tk.Label(frame3, text='Pruebas Clinicas 1', bg='gray')
        label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)
        self.prueba_seleccionada = tk.StringVar(frame3)
        self.prueba_seleccionada.set('--------------------------------------')
        self.menu_prueba = tk.OptionMenu(frame3,
                                         self.prueba_seleccionada,
                                         *self._pruebas.keys(),
                                         command=self.agregar_prueba)
        self.menu_prueba.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.E, pady=10)

    def obtener_pruebas(self):
        """ Actualizar pruebas disponibles desde base de datos"""
        query = """ 
            SELECT estudios_clinicos,
                   costo
            FROM price_list
            ORDER BY estudios_clinicos
            """
        self._pruebas = {prueba: costo for prueba, costo in self.run_query(query)}
        if not self._pruebas:
            self._pruebas = {'No hay estudios': 0}


    def agregar_prueba(self, prueba):
        costo = self._pruebas[prueba]
        print(costo) 

    def run_query(self, query, parameters=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = """
            CREATE TABLE price_list (
                estudios_clinicos text NOT NULL,
                costo float NOT NULL
            );"""
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()

        rows = [("Glucosa", 123.4),
                ('ANTIDOPING EN ORINA', 452.3),
                ('BIOMETRIA HEMATICA COMPLETA BHC', 652.48)
                ]
        query = """
            INSERT INTO price_list (estudios_clinicos, costo)
            VALUES (?, ?)
            """
        cursor.executemany(query, rows)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        root = tk.Tk()
        MainFrame(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        root.mainloop()

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        try:
            os.remove("test.db")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Se asume el uso de Python >= 3.7, en caso contrario los diccionarios no mantienen el orden de inserción y el orden alfabético retornado por la BD no se respetará. En caso contrario usar `collections.OrderedDict` en vez de un diccionario estándar.

Comment: Wooooow amigo JFSevilla, muchas gracias por la explicacion fue demasiado clara, en donde pude reproducir el codigo que me diste y logre adaptarlo, se ve perfectamente como se pueden tomar los estudios y los precios sin necesidad de tanto rollo, gracias a eso quite un boton para que se actualizara el subtotal, ademas de que se lograron eliminar los corchetes y en la interfaz se veia borroso en la parte de subtotal lo cual ya no hasta quedó eliminado

Comment: Por cierto amigo JFSevilla en el momento que se selecciona el estudio dentro del OptionMenu al momento de imprimir en pantalla me aparece como None, a que se debe eso??? o en que parte se guarda ya que no le he encontrado :S

Comment: ¿Te refieres a imprimir el estudio?¿Cómo y dónde  intentas obtener el estudio seleccionado? La selección actual se guarda en la StringVar (`print(self.prueba_seleccionada.get()`)), además se pasa al método `agregar_prueba` como argumento. ¿O te refieres al costo?

Comment: De hecho quiero imprimir el estudio en pantalla, (es que luego lo paso a una base de datos y me aparece como None :S) y lo estuve buscando por un rato, tal y como me dijiste lo imprimi desde el metodo agregar_prueba ademas ya logre ingresarlo a la base de datos, el costo fue mas rapido de encontrar e ingresarlo a la base de datos, de nuevo muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Amigo JFSevilla, estoy haciendo una modificacion y disculpa que este retomando el tema, se discutió el uso de un diccionario para mostrar el nombre del estudio y su precio, ahora busco mostrar ademas de lo anterior el precio de la maquila (Estudio, precio, maquila) de manera que cuando se seleccione el estudio aparte de que se despliegue el precio (que ya se hace gracias a tus comentarios) se despliegue el costo de la maquila la cual la guardaria en una variable y asi almacenarla en la base de datos, he intentado ajustarlo pero no me queda, por eso recurro a tus consejos